# how do you change the default font used by apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

We're doing a proof of concept test on Apache NiFi.  The font for the layout screen looks like it's about 10 pt, which is way too small

I can zoom the screen to 140%, but that makes everything bigger, and a lot less useful

How Do I simply change the font used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the font-size for particular areas of Apache NiFi you can simply update the appropriate css files found in:

```
nifi/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-ui/src/main/webapp/css/
```

Then rebuild and restart the application. Most of the time you can tell by the file names where the styles are applied within the application but you can also use your browsers developer tools to inspect the styles of any particular element in the UI and determine the precise file you will need to edit.